# Set values in a Pandas dataframe column with the value of another dataframe column where match between other two columns values (one with duplicates)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm newbe in Pandas and i'm stuck in gettin the code for do this:

df1 ('c-code' column is unordered and may contain duplicate values):

| c-code | c-text | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 970000 | null | 'val X' | 'val 1' |
| 932201 | null | 'val Y' | 'val 2' |
| 413220 | null | 'val Z' | 'val 3' |
| 932201 | null | 'val A' | 'val 0' |
| 932201 | null | 'val A' | 'val 0' |
| 213201 | null | 'val A' | 'val 0' |

df2 ('code' column is ordered an has unique values):

| code | text |
| --- | --- |
| 100101 | 'Some text 1' |
| 100102 | 'Some text 2' |
| 100103 | 'Some text 3' |
| ...... | ............. |
| 213201 | 'Some text 11' |
| ...... | ............. |
| 413220 | 'Some text 18' |
| ...... | ............. |
| 932201 | 'Some text 20' |
| ...... | ............. |
| 970000 | 'Some text 31' |
| ...... | ............. |
| 990090 | 'Some text 99' |

Desired df1:

| c-code | c-text | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 970000 | 'Some text 31' | 'val X' | 'val 1' |
| 932201 | 'Some text 20' | 'val Y' | 'val 2' |
| 413220 | 'Some text 18' | 'val Z' | 'val 3' |
| 932201 | 'Some text 20' | 'val A' | 'val 0' |
| 932201 | 'Some text 20' | 'val A' | 'val 0' |
| 213201 | 'Some text 11' | 'val A' | 'val 0' |

I have tried .loc like:

> df1.loc[df1['c-code'] == df2['code'], 'c-text'] = df_cpv['text']

with .merge too, but I haven't achieved anything good.

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: `df1['c-text'] = df1['c-code'].map(df2.set_index('code')['c-text'])`

Comment: Thank you very much @mozway your solution runs like a charm! Only have to modify last c-text' with 'text' like: `df1['c-text'] = df1['c-code'].map(df2.set_index('code')['text'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge is the right way to go! After merging there will be extra columns left, so additionally you should do some renaming and dropping.

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, how="left", left_on="c-code", right_on="code")
df3["c-text"] = df3["text"]
df3 = df3.drop(["text", "code"], axis=1)
print(df3)
```

Output:

```
   c-code          c-text Column B Column C
0  970000  'Some text 31'  'val X'  'val 1'
1  932201  'Some text 20'  'val Y'  'val 2'
2  413220  'Some text 18'  'val Z'  'val 3'
3  932201  'Some text 20'  'val A'  'val 0'
4  932201  'Some text 20'  'val A'  'val 0'
5  213201  'Some text 11'  'val A'  'val 0'
```

Comment: Many thanks Maria!! Your solution gave me knowledge in another poblem I had too.